# Macro to know whether ARC enabled or not in Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, xcode4

in same file we want to write code which supports ARC and non-ARC. For that some macro required.

```
#ifdef ARC_ENABLED 
NSLog(@" ARC enabled ");
#else
NSLog(@" ARC disabled ");
[self release];
#endif
```

How to achieve  this macro, Does any kind of macro available?
Please let me know. Advance thanks for support 
Note: ARC_ENABLED Just i have written for example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional compilation when using ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447090/conditional-compilation-when-using-arc)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically detect automatic reference counting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700661/how-to-programmatically-detect-automatic-reference-counting)

Answer (score 27):

There is an objective C macro `__has_feature`, you can use that to check whether arc is enabled for not.

From [Clang Language Extension documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html)

> **Automatic reference counting**
>
> Clang provides support for automated reference counting in
>   Objective-C, which eliminates the need for manual
>   retain/release/autorelease message sends. There are two feature macros
>   associated with automatic reference counting:
>   `__has_feature(objc_arc)` indicates the availability of automated
>   reference counting in general, while `__has_feature(objc_arc_weak)`
>   indicates that automated reference counting also includes support for
>   `__weak` pointers to Objective-C objects.

The section [Feature checking macro's](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#feature-checking-macros) is a very good read.

You can use it like this..

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    //Do manual memory management...
#else
    //Usually do nothing...
#endif
```

The code part shamelessly copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700661/how-to-programmatically-detect-automatic-reference-counting/10700791#10700791).

Comment: @Krishnabhadra, how to define __has_feature(objc_arc), I did something like below #ifndef __has_feature
#define __has_feature(x) 0
#endif
#ifndef __has_extension
#define __has_extension __has_feature // Compatibility with pre-3.0 compilers.
#endif

#if __has_feature(objc_arc) && __clang_major__ >= 3
#define ARC_ENABLED 1
#else
#define ARC_ENABLED 0
#endif // __has_feature(objc_arc)
 But it seems it does not work, i have used retain and release when i enabled ARC in project, gives error

Comment: +1 Great answer. `__has_feature` is a wonderful macro, and can be used for more than just ARC - you can check for a lot of Objective-C features (ex. modules).

Answer (score 2):

The following will define `USING_ARC`, `USING_MRC` & `USING_GC` to be 0 or 1, along with a few sanity checks:

```
// Utility macros (undefined below)

#define PREFIX_ONE(a) 1##a
#define EMPTY_DEFINE(a) (PREFIX_ONE(a) == 1)

// Memory management kind

#if !defined(USING_GC)
#  if defined(__OBJC_GC__)
#     define USING_GC 1
#  else
#    define USING_GC 0
#  endif
#elif EMPTY_DEFINE(USING_GC) 
#   undef USING_GC
#   define USING_GC 1
#endif

#if !defined(USING_ARC)
#  if __has_feature(objc_arc)
#     define USING_ARC 1
#  else
#    define USING_ARC 0
#  endif
#elif EMPTY_DEFINE(USING_ARC)
#   undef USING_ARC
#   define USING_ARC 1
#endif

#if !defined(USING_MRC)
#  if USING_ARC || USING_GC
#     define USING_MRC 0
#  else
#    define USING_MRC 1
#  endif
#elif EMPTY_DEFINE(USING_MRC)
#   undef USING_MRC
#   define USING_MRC 1
#endif

// Remove utility

#undef PREFIX_ONE
#undef EMPTY_DEFINE

// Sanity checks

#if USING_GC
#   if USING_ARC || USING_MRC
#      error "Cannot specify GC and RC memory management"
#   endif
#elif USING_ARC
#   if USING_MRC
#      error "Cannot specify ARC and MRC memory management"
#   endif
#elif !USING_MRC
#   error "Must specify GC, ARC or MRC memory management"
#endif

#if USING_ARC
#   if MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6
#      error "ARC requires at least 10.6"
#   endif
#endif
```

Place that in a suitable .h included in your project .pch

You can now `#if USING_x` to control conditional compilation anywhere.

Also you can rule out some files from compiling under certain memory models by including, for example, at the top of the file:

```
#if USING_GC | USING_ARC
   #error "Sorry, this file only works with MRC"
#endif
```